# proof verification: algebraic extension (of F) containing all zeros of F[x] is algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This is Exercise 32.34 in Fraleigh's book, 'A first course in abstract algebra'.

> Show that if $E$ is an algebraic extension of a field $F$ and contains all zeros of every $f(x) \in F[x]$, then $E$ is algebraically closed field.

Below is my proof which I want to get verified. I'm quite certain with my proof, but since this is the first time for me to study algebra, it feels like I'm missing something.

> Suppose that there exist polynomial $g(x) \in E[x]$ which has no zero in $E$. Then by Kronecker's Theorem, there exists field $K$ such that $E \le K$ and $K$ contains zero of $g$, which I will denote by $\alpha$. Then we have $F \le E \le E(\alpha) \le K$, since $E(\alpha)$ is the smallest field which contains both $E$ and $\alpha$. Since $E$ is an algebraic extension of $F$ (by assumption) and $E(\alpha)$ is an algebraic extension of $E$ (because $g(\alpha)=0$), $E(\alpha)$ is an algebraic extension of $F$. Thus, $\alpha$ is a zero of polynomial in $F[x]$. By assumption in question, we obtain $\alpha \in E$, a contradiction.

Thank you for reading my question. Any comments (including non-mathematical advices) will help me really lot.

Comment: It's correct, though you don't really need to distinguish between $K$ and $E(\alpha)$. The $K$ given in the proof of Kronecker's theorem *is* $K:=E(\alpha):=E[X]/(g)$, where $g$ is an irreducible factor of $f$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Oh, I see. Thanks for your helpful comment!